# adduser.conf NAME_REGEX is not working

Tags: regex, adduser

I am trying to set a rule for new users.

I changed the `/etc/adduser.conf` file by adding the line:

```
NAME_REGEX="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{5,9}$"
```

but after that, the system is not accepting any user.. always says that it doesnt match the `NAME_REGEX` in `/etc/adduser.conf`!

When I comment the line, it accepts any user, but I don't want that neither! I want that all users have the following policy:

1. must start with a CAPS-ON-Letter
2. Username must have minimum 5 letter and max 9 letters. 
   for ex. "Newuser" should be accepted, "newuser" not and "Hereisanewuser" neither!

How should I proceed?

Comment: anyone has an idea on this? it would be really helpful! i have a unix project on the university, and i cannot get further without help on this point :/

Comment: Do you want only alphabetic characters i.e. `a-z`  or `A-Z`?

Answer (score 3):

After testing several of the above regular expressions for `NAME_REGEX` with no success (html code is hiding some `\` characters, at least), I managed to write a proper and working one including the period symbol, just like this:

```
NAME_REGEX="^[a-z][-a-z0-9_\.]*\$?$"
```

This means: Begin with `a-z`, followed by any number of dashes or `a-z` or `0-9` or underscores or periods, and may be ended with an optional `$`.

(Note that even the default commented out configuration line in some Debian-based distributions' `adduser.conf` file, have the `$` syntax wrong, just `\$` instead of `\$?$`).

Comment: Uh, *why* do you want to allow a `$` in a username?

Comment: $ at the end of the username can be useful for samba compliance.

Comment: It's not necessary to escape the dot.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
NAME_REGEX="^[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{4,8}$"
```

This will match `[A-Z]` at the start of the name and them the name can contain any alphabetic characters i.e. `[A-Za-z]` and the total characters would be between 5 to 9.

On the other hand if you want only lowercase letters after the first uppercase:

```
NAME_REGEX="^[A-Z][a-z]{4,8}$"
```

Furthermore if you want any number or any upper/lowercase (using character classes):

```
NAME_REGEX="^[A-Z]([[:alpha:]]|[[:digit:]]){4,8}$"
```

Using ranges:

```
NAME_REGEX="^[A-Z]([A-Za-z]|[0-9]){4,8}$"
```

Answer (score 2):

There are correct answers already, and the answer I'm going to provide suggests in the end to do exactly what the other answers suggested to do already, so technically this is a duplicate, but I think that to give an explanation it's better here.

```
NAME_REGEX="[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{5,9}$"
```

This regex matches any string whose last part is a 6-10 character long substring starting with a capital letter, so it matches strings such as "usErname", "USErname", "12Ername".

Leaving aside the fact that this is not something you're expecting, the fact that no username is being accepted is probably (and sorry for the probably, but [`/etc/adduser.conf` is very poorly documented](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/adduser.conf.5.html)) due to the fact the regex must be anchored both at the start and at the end (the other possibility being you having been always testing using usernames not matching the above criterium).

So as it has been suggested already, first anchor the start of the string:

```
NAME_REGEX="^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{5,9}$"
```

Then you can remove the number of occurences specifier `{1}` after the character class `[A-Z]`, since by default a character class matches only one occurence:

```
NAME_REGEX="^[A-Z][a-z]{5,9}$"
```

Then you should decrement the minimum and maximum number of occurences in the number of occurences specifier `{5,9}` to `4` and `8`, since you want to accept strings that are 5-9 characters long:

```
NAME_REGEX="^[A-Z][a-z]{4,8}$"
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested this and it works.

```
NAME_REGEX="^[A-Z][a-z]{4,8}$"
```

similar: [regex-to-check-if-the-first-character-is-uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274562/regex-to-check-if-the-first-character-is-uppercase)

Comment: This is incorrect..it will match names between 6 to 10 characters, also only lowercase chars can occur after the first uppercase..

Comment: @heemayl you're right, i fixed the character length and OP only stated the first character must be caps and judging by the posted expression I went with the remainding as lowercase.